# LinkedIn JS API Share

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to pass in more than a URL to share when using the LinkedIn JS API.

My code is:

```
IN.UI.Share().params({
    url: 'http://www.example.com'
}).place.();
```

Now I have tried to pass in other params like:

```
IN.UI.Share().params({
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    title: 'A Title',
    summary: 'A Small summary'
}).place.();
```

But that did wot work. It seems to just ignore those extra params.

I know I can do it using the custom share functionality:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={articleUrl}&title={articleTitle}&summary={articleSummary}&source={articleSource}
```

But I want to use the JS API so I can get back a token to verify if it was posted properly. With the `shareArticle` way it takes about 20-30 seconds to actually verify if it was shared using this: (https://developer.linkedin.com/retrieving-share-counts-custom-buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this. The Linkdin Javascript API and Linkdin Share button relies completely on meta tags to scrape information. Such a Pity.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `og:` property tags on the page that you are sharing, that way LinkedIn knows that the `title`, `image`, etc., fields, are all actually appropriate and right for the site.  You can set them like so...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

Works for my site!

[image]

You can always use the [**LinkedIn Poster Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) on your site's URL to make sure you did it right!